# querria preguntar como puedo evitar la injection con mysql

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber como puedo evitar la injección SQL a las base de datos , no se en que parte del codigo se necesita :/

```
MySqlConnection conexion = new ConexionBBDD().conecta();
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("" +
            "SELECT * from usuarios where " +
            " usuario = '" + textBox1.Text +
            "' and pass ='" + textBox2.Text+
            "' ;", conexion);
```

Answer (score 1):

Todo lo que se introduzca a través de tecleo por parte de un cliente, es susceptible de inyección de código, con lo que no te recomiendo la concatenación, si no una consulta con parámetros:

```
MySqlConnection conexion = new ConexionBBDD().conecta();
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from usuarios where usuario = @usuario and pass = @pass ;", conexion);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(@usuario, textBox1.Text);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(@pass, textBox2.Text);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudó mucho la verdad